# sed: -e expression #1, char XX: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use a regular expression with the command `sed` to substitute any 8 consecutive digits with a specific 8 digits in a whole file. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but I keep getting an error saying the command is unterminated. Any idea why ?

`sed -i 's/d\{8\}/20170526' ./somefolder/somefile.xml`

the error says char17 which corresponds to the `/` before `20170526`

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/d\{8\}/20170526/' ./somefolder/somefile.xml`

Comment: Mind the trailing `/` - correct syntax of the `s` command for `sed` is `s/replace_this/with_that/`, not `s/replace_this/with_that`

Comment: `d` doesn't match digits. Maybe `\d` does, but better use `[0-9]`, or even better `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: Also, character 17 is the last character of the command itself, not including the `sed -i` – and that's exactly at the end of the command where the `/` is missing.

Comment: From `man sed`: `s/regexp/replacement/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 separators (a slash in your case) for a sed switch statement.

```
sed -eE 's/[0-9]{8}/20170526/' ./somefolder/somefile.xml
```

Comment: `s` stands for "substitute", not "switch".

Comment: "p" stands for pedantic.